# Oil Futures and Prices

Tags: united-states, futures, commodities

I am looking at the following chain of oil futures:
     https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/light-sweet-crude.html

Based upon what I am seeing, the market thinks that the crude oil prices are going to fall. That does not seem right to me. Is there something I am missing?

Bob

Comment: Why does that not seem right?

Comment: @JohnFx I would expect the price of oil to be going up over time, in part, because of inflation. I also expect the price of steel per ton to be higher 10 years from now then it is today.

Comment: In the summer of 2008 a little more than 10 years ago the price was above $140, so one could say that it has done nothing but drop over the last 10 years,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are seeing the price for December lower than November?

[image]

This is backwardation, ref. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_backwardation)

> Normal backwardation, also sometimes called backwardation, is the
>   market condition wherein the price of a commodities' forward or
>   futures contract is trading below the expected spot price at contract
>   maturity.

Also, from [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/07/contango_backwardation.asp)

> Normal backwardation is when the futures price is below the expected
>   future spot price. This is desirable for speculators who are net long
>   in their positions: they want the futures price to increase. So,
>   normal backwardation is when the futures prices are increasing.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there something I am missing?

With oil or in general anything; predicting the future is complex; although there are algorithms and experts and theories; they are often not accurate. Else everyone would have become millionaire.

If the market sees the prices of Oil to reduce; it could be due to various reasons that the market **believes** in. Note I say believes in, does not mean it is correct. Only time will tell if it was right or wrong.

Some of the reasons could be; speculating / simplified / opinion

- Curbs in Iran will get lifted. That is one of the reason for higher oil price. Unrest in Venezuela can go away to stable political environment.
- Fracting can result in larger oils. There could be forecasts of some oil reservoirs being found. Takes few years or a decade to develop and can add.
- Alternative technology in Batteries can reduce the dependency on Oil for automobile.
- Various alternatives in Solar / Wind can reduce other needs for Oil
- Other such reasons.